# PackageManager not running on PowerShell 5

Tags: windows, powershell

When running powershell 5 (default)
PS> get-package

Error states:
"Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

We can see event ID 1000 and event ID 1026.

1000:
Faulting application name: powershell.exe , version: 10.0.17763.1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version 10.0.177763.3532
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Source: Application Error

1026:
Application: powershell.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Access.Violation.Exception ... ...
Source: .NET Runtime and then automatically closes powershell.
Powershell 7 and ISE can run get-package without any problem.

Any insights?

Thanks,

get-package
install-module

not working suddenly 2 weeks ago.

Comment: You are running a version of Net from 2008 (4.0).  You are trying to mix powershell version 7 with version 1.  From cmd.exe check the PSModulePath >Set  You want to have path uses new version of powershell.

Comment: @jdweng I will check. by default, laptops don't have powershell 7. It just happened suddenly. I remember applying OneDrive to Documents, so the default path of PSModule will be changed from  

_C:\Users\%username%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules_
to
_C:\Users\%username%\OneDrive - (company)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules_

OR

does that mean that there is a chance that this is due to .Net update?

Comment: PSModulePath is an environmental variable that doesn't change unless a new application is installed.  Win10 and Win11 comes with Powershell installed so I don't know why you are saying Laptops do not have Powershell.  Maybe Powershell was recently installed in your laptops.

Comment: @jdweng no I am referring to PS7. we didn't install nor update powershell. we are doing monthly updates for .net though.

Any more clues that you can think of? 
Install-module;
Get-Package;
any related to packemanagement are not working anymore suddenly.

Comment: You can use : get-command get-package to see version of package.  Following show how to locate folder of a cmdlet : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/find-command?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: get-command get-package

Pasting here for reference:
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-Package                                        1.0.0.1    PackageManagement

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  Net 4.0 was a 32 bit version of Windows that was release for WinXp and used dlls in c:\Windows\System32.  Windows 10/11 uses dll in c:\Windows\SysWow64.  Your exception say error is in System32. I think error has something to do with following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/starting-windows-powershell?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: See "PowerShell" at bottom of following : https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_powermanagementevent?force_isolation=true

Comment: Solved it. I ran powershell using Syswow64 and found a clue about carbonblack agent.
CBagent 7.1 causing it and upgraded to 7.3.

Thanks,

Comment: Check the PSModulePath variable from Start Button : Edit Environmental Variable.  It may need to be changed.